# What is the expiration/permission scope of Codepipeline manual approval token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

When you add a Manual approval stage to your codepipeline, codepipeline will issue a token to [approve or reject the pipeline.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals-approve-or-reject.html)

What are the **Permissions scope or expiration** of this token? I couldn't find this information in any documentation

The only [information](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/codepipeline/get-pipeline-state.html) available about these tokens:

> The system-generated token used to identify a unique approval request. The token for each open approval request can be obtained using the GetPipelineState command. It is used to validate that the approval request corresponding to this token is still valid.

I want to consider a situation where this token is leaked so that I why I wanted to know the scope of this token.

Comment: its just a nonce value.

Comment: But still, it doesn't answer my question that what are the permissions this value holds for a particular codepipeline resource or expiration time

Comment: There are no permissions or expiration time. It’s a magic string that’s a key to approve the job. That’s it. It’s not an access token

Comment: Thank you Daniel, is there any supporting document to support your comment? If yes feel free to post an answer with document link, will be happy to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far is expiration time is concerned, it's 7 days.

I have check Cloudwatch logs, and even this AWS doc supports this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/limits.html

> Length of time before a manual approval action times out -> 7 days

For permission I think this is a "nonce" value whose importance is only when it's appended to manual approval link. So if someone figures out the pipeline name, region name then only token will have the value that if they do that within 7 days the token was issued.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codepipeline/pipelines/pipeline-name/view?region=region-name#/Approve/Approval/approve/xyz-123